# Problem with scaling of objects in Gazebo gui

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there,
I am trying to scale the object's visual and collision size (geometry => size tags) in Gazebo gui.
Upon changing the value the following exception gets thrown:
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'gazebo::common::Exception'
Aborted (core dumped)

Version 2:
I also got the following bt:

#0  0x00007ffff3a6d425 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

#1  0x00007ffff3a70b8b in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

#2  0x00007ffff43bf69d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

#3  0x00007ffff43bd846 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

#4  0x00007ffff43bd873 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

#5  0x00007ffff43bd9b6 in __cxa_rethrow () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

#6  0x00007ffff598816c in QEventLoop::exec(QFlagsQEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4

#7  0x00007ffff598cf67 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4

#8  0x000000000059d273 in gazebo::gui::run (_argc=3, _argv=0x7fffffffdbd8) at /home/lawnmower/work/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo-hg/gazebo/gui/Gui.cc:195

#9  0x000000000059567b in main (_argc=3, _argv=0x7fffffffdbd8) at /home/lawnmower/work/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo-hg/gazebo/gui/main.cc:2

This has been noted in https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk in ROS fuerte which pulls in the deprecated_parser_sdf_1.2_support branch of Gazebo. OS: Ubuntu 12.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1698/problem-with-scaling-of-objects-in-gazebo-gui/) by [dejanpan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/30/dejanpan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 60 on 2013-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The scaling feature was never implemented, and resulted in a segault. We have resolved this problem in gazebo 1.5 by removing the GUI based scaling feature.

We'll spend more time on this in the near future to implement it properly.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0